# App crashes when tested on mobile - Android

Tags: java, android, facebook

I wrote a simple Facebook login app for android. When I tested it in mobile, the app crashes. I debugged it and addedfew breakpoints, and it said like this:

```
this    FragmentManagerImpl  (id=830029495424)  
    mActive null    
    mActivity   MainActivity  (id=830029490984) 
    mAdded  null    
    mAvailBackStackIndices  null    
    mAvailIndices   null    
    mBackStack  null    
    mBackStackChangeListeners   null    
    mBackStackIndices   null    
    mContainer  null    
    mCreatedMenus   null    
    mCurState   0   
    mDestroyed  false   
    mExecCommit FragmentManagerImpl$1  (id=830029496320)    
    mExecutingActions   false   
    mHavePendingDeferredStart   false   
    mNeedMenuInvalidate false   
    mNoTransactionsBecause  null    
    mParent null    
    mPendingActions null    
    mStateArray null    
    mStateBundle    null    
    mStateSaved false   
    mTmpActions null    
activity    MainActivity  (id=830029490984) 
    mActionBar  null    
    mActivityInfo   ActivityInfo  (id=830029434912) 
        applicationInfo ApplicationInfo  (id=830029435240)  
        configChanges   0   
        descriptionRes  0   
        enabled true    
        exported    true    
        flags   512 
        icon    0   
        labelRes    2131361837  
        launchMode  0   
        logo    0   
        metaData    null    
        name    "com.cheerz.citizengage.MainActivity" (id=830029435016) 
        nonLocalizedLabel   null    
        packageName "com.cheerz.citizengage" (id=830029435144)  
        parentActivityName  null    
        permission  null    
        processName "com.cheerz.citizengage" (id=830029436288)  
        screenOrientation   -1  
        softInputMode   0   
        targetActivity  null    
        taskAffinity    "com.cheerz.citizengage" (id=830029436384)  
        theme   0   
        uiOptions   0   
    mainFragment    null    
    mAllLoaderManagers  null    
    mAllLoaderManagers  null    
    mApplication    Application  (id=830029459888)  
    mBase   ContextImpl  (id=830029497760)  
    mBase   ContextImpl  (id=830029497760)  
    mByPassTouchEvent   false   
    mCalled false   
    mChangingConfigurations false   
    mCheckedForLoaderManager    false   
    mCheckedForLoaderManager    false   
    mComponent  ComponentName  (id=830029434400)    
    mConfigChangeFlags  0   
    mContainer  Activity$1  (id=830029491400)   
    mContainer  FragmentActivity$2  (id=830029497744)   
    mCreated    false   
    mCurrentConfig  Configuration  (id=830029500008)    
    mDecor  null    
    mDefaultKeyMode 0   
    mDefaultKeySsb  null    
    mDestroyed  false   
    mEmbeddedID null    
    mEnableDefaultActionBarUp   false   
    mFinished   false   
    mFragments  FragmentManagerImpl  (id=830029491280)  
    mFragments  FragmentManagerImpl  (id=830029495424)  
    mHandler    Handler  (id=830029491568)  
    mHandler    FragmentActivity$1  (id=830029492456)   
    mIdent  1103684784  
    mInflater   PhoneLayoutInflater  (id=830029501560)  
    mInstanceTracker    StrictMode$InstanceTracker  (id=830029491440)   
    mInstrumentation    Instrumentation  (id=830029455328)  
    mIntent Intent  (id=830029434136)   
    mLastNonConfigurationInstances  null    
    mLoaderManager  null    
    mLoaderManager  null    
    mLoadersStarted false   
    mLoadersStarted false   
    mMainThread ActivityThread  (id=830029429096)   
    mManagedCursors ArrayList  (id=830029491416)    
    mManagedDialogs null    
    mMenuInflater   null    
    mOptionsMenuInvalidated false   
    mOverrideConfiguration  null    
    mParent null    
    mReallyStopped  false   
    mResources  Resources  (id=830029448856)    
    mResultCode 0   
    mResultData null    
    mResumed    false   
    mResumed    false   
    mRetaining  false   
    mSearchManager  null    
    mStartedActivity    false   
    mStopped    false   
    mStopped    false   
    mTemporaryPause false   
    mTheme  Resources$Theme  (id=830029503880)  
    mThemeResource  2131427567  
    mTitle  "Citizengage" (id=830029499824) 
    mTitleColor 0   
    mTitleReady false   
    mToken  BinderProxy  (id=830029434816)  
    mUiThread   Thread  (id=830019799456)   
    mVisibleFromClient  true    
    mVisibleFromServer  false   
    mWindow PhoneWindow  (id=830029500152)  
    mWindowAdded    false   
    mWindowManager  WindowManagerImpl  (id=830029503856)    
container   FragmentActivity$2  (id=830029497744)   
parent  null
```

And here is my `MainFragment.java` code:

```
package com.cheerz.citizengage;

import java.util.Arrays;

import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setFragment(this);
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes", "user_status"));

        return view;
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        }
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
               (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

}
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
package com.cheerz.citizengage;

import com.facebook.AppEventsLogger;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private MainFragment mainFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
            mainFragment = new MainFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
            .commit();
        } else {
            // Or set the fragment from restored state info
            mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();

      // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
      AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();

      // Logs 'app deactivate' App Event.
      AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
    }
}
```

Where is the error? How can I fix it? 
`logcat`

```
01-13 14:19:56.185: I/dalvikvm(20934): Could not find method bolts.AppLinks.getAppLinkData, referenced from method com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.setSourceApplication
01-13 14:19:56.185: W/dalvikvm(20934): VFY: unable to resolve static method 8089: Lbolts/AppLinks;.getAppLinkData (Landroid/content/Intent;)Landroid/os/Bundle;
01-13 14:19:56.185: D/dalvikvm(20934): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x002e
01-13 14:19:56.195: D/AndroidRuntime(20934): Shutting down VM
01-13 14:19:56.195: W/dalvikvm(20934): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4108f930)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bolts.AppLinks
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.setSourceApplication(AppEventsLogger.java:1000)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp(AppEventsLogger.java:277)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp(AppEventsLogger.java:260)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at com.cheerz.citizengage.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:37)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1202)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5404)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2830)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2882)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
01-13 14:19:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20934):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your log error.

Comment: is this logcat error text ???

Comment: it seems not completed log error.update error once again and also post your mainactivity from whre you call this fragment

Comment: I updated the question again. Please check

Comment: check your libs  bolts-android-1.1.2.jar exists or not.if exists configure build path properly.if its no there add it to your libs and configure build path properly. dont forget to tick the check box in build path.

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved at my side. download [bolts-android1.1.2](https://www.versioneye.com/java/com.parse.bolts:bolts-android/1.1.2) and put into \libs folder. then open the project properties-> java Build Path-> Project tab , Add Facebook SDK. (Facebook SDK libs must be attached with project